# Is there a North Korean "interests section", representation of NK interests, or consular arrangement for NK citizens, in the United States?

Tags: united-states, north-korea

The United States and North Korea do not have diplomatic relations with each other, and therefore neither hosts a diplomatic mission of the other, although NK does maintain a mission to the United Nations in New York. In NK, an arrangement exists whereby Sweden provides consular services to US citizens in NK, acting as the "protecting power" of the US in that country.

What about the other way around? Is there a NK "interests" section in the US, a consular arrangement for NK citizens, a protecting power arrangement, or some other kind of proxy or third-party arrangement or similar, for citizen or business protection or state representation or both, and if so what are the details??

I am aware that South Korea views at least most NK citizens as its own citizens, but that is not what I am asking about.

Comment: Agreed. And will add: Likely not. But if there was, it surely would have been closed and vacated by now.

Comment: AIUI any NK citizen in the USA is either a government official, or accompanied and closely monitored by said officials. So they wouldn't need consular services in the normal sense. Presumably things like secure communication with the NK government could be handled by the UN mission in New York.

Comment: Official communications that the US authorities need or wish to deliver or receive in the US may well be handled by the NK mission to the UN, but I would like to know for certain. Before Cuba and the US restored diplomatic relations, Cuba kept an interests section in the US as part of the Swiss embassy at the same time as a mission to the UN in New York.

Comment: @A.fm - NK hasn't ended the arrangement in Pyongyang whereby US interests are handled through the Swedish embassy, which I would have thought they'd do if there were a similar arrangement in Washington DC and the US ended it.

Comment: There is no North Korean section within a foreign embassy near or in the United States. For some reason answers are mass negged here, even though it is the only valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [US State Department](https://www.state.gov/r/pa/ei/bgn/2792.htm), there are two special US appointed envoys, otherwise North Korea is represented in the US via the UN.

> The United States and North Korea do not have diplomatic relations. The Swedish Embassy in North Korea is the U.S. protecting power and provides limited consular services to U.S. citizens. The U.S. Special Representative for North Korea Policy is Ambassador Joseph Yun. The U.S. Special Envoy for North Korean Human Rights Issues is Vacant. The Acting U.S. Special Envoy for the Six-Party Talks is Mark Lambert.
>
> North Korea has no embassy in Washington, DC, but it is represented in the United States through its mission to the United Nations.